# wordpress: the_time returns wierd dates

Tags: wordpress, date, time

I have a blog page that collects all posts in "news" category, but all posts show the same date (5 may 2013) but with different name for day of the week

this is the code:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=post&category_name=news&paged='.$paged);
?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="title">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="postmeta">  <span>Posted on  <?php the_time('l, n F Y'); ?></span></div>
```

this is the_time output:

```
Posted on Saturday, 5 May 2013

Posted on Tuesday, 5 May 2013

Posted on Tuesday, 5 May 2013

Posted on Monday, 5 May 2013
```

Not a single post or page is posted on 5 may... i have no idea to fix this... please help!

EDIT:

found the problem, changed this:

```
<?php the_time('l, n F Y'); ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php the_time('l, j F Y'); ?>
```

Comment: the permalink & titles are ok ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with `<?php the_time('l, n F Y'); ?>`. The `n` you specified refers to the numerical number of the month, `May` is `5`. What you need is `j`.

```
<?php the_time('l, j F Y'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Go wp-admin in "post" option edit your post is "Published on" option edit set your date and time.
> same step in page option.
> ```

Comment: posts dates are all different